# VB.NET Text Scores Program RunTime Error

Tags: vb.net

I needed to create a program that will take a Test Score from a user, store the score and the number of scores, calculate the avg score, as well as determine and display the highest score. It also has a button to clear all the values out and reset. I've written code for the program and it doesn't appear to have a any compiler errors. However, when I run the program and enter a score I get an exception. Here is the message....

"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index."

It doesn't matter what value I put in. I keep getting this exception

My code is down below. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? Thanks!

Public Class Form1

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim dTestScore As Decimal

    If IsNumeric(dTestScore >= 0) Then
        Call Scores()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value. ", "User Error")
    End If
End Sub

Sub Scores()
    Dim ANumberOfScores As New ArrayList
    Dim iNumberOfScores As Integer
    Dim dTestScore As Decimal
    Dim ScoreTotal As Decimal

    For Each dTestScore In ANumberOfScores
        iNumberOfScores = ++1
        txtNumberofScores.Text = iNumberOfScores
    Next

    For dTestScore = 0 To ANumberOfScores.Count - 1
        ScoreTotal = ScoreTotal + ANumberOfScores(iNumberOfScores)
        txtAverageScores.Text = ScoreTotal / iNumberOfScores
    Next

    ANumberOfScores.Sort()
    ANumberOfScores.Reverse()

    Dim MaxScore = ANumberOfScores(0)
    txtBestScore.Text = MaxScore
End Sub




Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    txtAverageScores.Clear()
    txtBestScore.Clear()
    txtNumberofScores.Clear()
    txtTestScore.Clear()


End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: dTestScore is always zero in your click event.

Comment: Wow.  I am really shocked that `++1` compiles.  Apparently the compiler treats it the same as just `1`, but it just seems invalid.  Anyone know why it considers that valid?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I think it's just setting it positive.  --1 is actually  positive one, while ---1 is back to negative one.

Comment: @LarsTech Ah!  Right...  I never would have thought of using `+` to indicate positive.  I just asked it as a question.  I'd be happy to give you credit if you answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

Should:

```
For dTestScore = 0 To ANumberOfScores.Count - 1
    ScoreTotal = ScoreTotal + ANumberOfScores(iNumberOfScores)
    txtAverageScores.Text = ScoreTotal / iNumberOfScores
Next
```

read:

```
For dTestScore = 0 To ANumberOfScores.Count - 1
    ScoreTotal = ScoreTotal + ANumberOfScores(dTestScore)
    txtAverageScores.Text = ScoreTotal / iNumberOfScores
Next
```

`iNumberOfScores` = 1 more than `ANumberOfScores.Count` (from your posted code) hence the exception you got.