# What does ++1 mean

Tags: vb.net

I just saw some sample code that someone posted ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719731/vb-net-text-scores-program-runtime-error?noredirect=1#comment34623712_22719731)) that set an integer variable equal to `++1`.  I was shocked that the VB.NET compiler would accept that as valid syntax.  For instance, this compiles:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
i = ++1
i = ++1
Console.WriteLine(i)  ' Outputs "1"
```

As best I can tell, it seems to ignore the pluses and just use the value that follows it.  For instance:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
i = ++10
Console.WriteLine(i)  ' Outputs "10"
```

So my question is, why is that valid syntax?  Is there some rule for the `+` operator that I'm totally unaware of.  As far as I knew, that was invalid and `++` was not, itself, an operator in VB.NET.

Comment: Why would it not be valid? Unary operators (like `-1` to indicate a negative number or `+1` to indicate a positive) are supported in VB.net, as they are in the majority of other languages. `++1` simply means "positive postive 1", which is the same as "positive (postive 1)", which is the same as saying "positive 1".

Comment: i = +-1 works also..... or i=+3+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike in some other languages, it’s just a sign. Signs can be duplicated – `+-++1` works, `---3` works, and `Not Not Not Not condition` works as well.